# Installing apache 2.4.27 for win 8.1 64bit

Tags: php, apache, visual-c++

I am installing apache httpd 2.4.27 for win 8.1 and PHP. Whenever i open *cmd* and type the command **c:/apache24/bin/httpd -k install** , it says that **VCRUNTIME140.dll** is missing. Please help fast.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is exactly that - probably worth installing the 2015 C++ redist libraries. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: I already tried to do that from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: But it is not installing properly. Showing error 0x80240017

Comment: Did you even try to research the error code? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/microsoft-visual-c-2015-redistributable-setup/051c3d6e-ebab-457e-acae-4d4847937ccc

Comment: Yes. And I even performed the clean boot as told. But nothing helped